# Why do sprites with the same setPosition point appear so far apart?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Given the following code, why are the Circle and Rectangle images displaying so far apart?

```
CGPoint center = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
[rectangle setPosition:center];
[circle setPosition:ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2)];
```

Here is the code used to create the Rectangle:

```
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 255);
glLineWidth(2);
CGPoint vertices2[] = { ccp(79,299), ccp(134,299), ccp(134,229), ccp(79,229) };
ccDrawPoly(vertices2, 4, YES);
```

[image]

```
-(id) init {
if((self = [super init])) {
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGB565];
    background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"blue-shooting-stars.png"];
    background.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_Default];
    Circle *circle = [[Circle alloc] init];
    [circle setPosition:ccp(winSize.width/2.0f, winSize.height/2.0f)];

    CGPoint center = ccp(winSize.width/2.0f, winSize.height/2.0f);

    Rectangle *rectangle = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
    [rectangle setPosition:center];

    [self addChild:circle];
    [self addChild:rectangle];
}
return self;
```

}

Comment: Are these images, or something that you are drawing?

Comment: If they are something you are drawing, what does the drawing code look like for the rectangle (the circle looks pretty nice)

Comment: Drawing both Circle and Rectangle.  When the Rectangle is actually on the screen, it looks like a Rectangle :)  Even if I remove the circle, the Rectangle stays in the same position, I guess I would have expected it to be in the same location the circle is in now.

Comment: show me the code where you initialize rectangle =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set position for your rectangle to the center of the screen. Then you draw first vertice with coordinates (79.f, 299.f). So it draws in the right-top corner. Because it draws relative to the Rectangle's instance position.